# jquery contents() returns text node for each character in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I am implementing a parser that looks for text nodes matching patterns at the top level of a contenteditable div. My current code:

```
//$this is the jQuery object of the contenteditable div
$this.keydown(function(event){
    //space bar or enter key
    if(event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13){
      // see how many nodes there are in the div
      alert($this.contents().length); 
      $this.contents().each(function(){
          //check if it is a text node
          if(this.nodeType == 3){ 
              //echo if it is a text node
              alert(this.data); 
           }
      });
});
```

With the content "Check it out", firefox and chrome output something like the following:

"1" (the first alert)
"check it out" (the second alert)

While IE8 will output the following:
12 (the first alert)
followed by 12 alerts, one for each character.

Anyhoo, what I would like to do is get the all characters into an individual text node in IE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a DOM method for this: [`normalize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-normalize) (see also [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.normalize)). You need to call it on an ancestor of the text nodes you want to normalize, for example their parent. `normalize()` works on the whole subtree of the node for which it's called, so you can call it once outside the `each()` loop.

```
$this[0].normalize();
```

However, this method crashes the whole browser in some circumstances in IE 6 and possibly later versions of IE. You may need to write your own. Here's my implementation:

```
function normalize(node) {
    var child = node.firstChild, nextChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            while ((nextChild = child.nextSibling) && nextChild.nodeType == 3) {
                child.appendData(nextChild.data);
                node.removeChild(nextChild);
            }
        } else {
            normalize(child);
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

Comment: Had not realized who answered my question... THANKS for your [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library Tim!